# Getting a Sharepoint site collection's owner with Graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

How do I get a Sharepoint Online site collection's owner with the Graph API?

[This page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/site_getbypath) of the documents seems to suggest that getting a site collection's root site returns its owner, however it didn't work when I tested it in Graph Explorer.

Am I missing some parameters, are there other APIs, or is it simply impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I missing some parameters

No

> are there other APIs

No

> or is it simply impossible?

It is possible, but the api is still in development. Current [endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/site_getbypath) is primarily intended to preview and evaluation.

> **Important**: APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are in
>   preview and are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production
>   applications is not supported.

The response format for stable version endpoint:

```
{
  "id": "contoso.sharepoint.com,2C712604-1370-44E7-A1F5-426573FDA80A,2D2244C3-251A-49EA-93A8-39E1C3A060FE",
  "displayName": "OneDrive Team Site",
  "name": "1drvteam",
  "createdDateTime": "2017-05-09T20:56:00Z",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-05-09T20:56:01Z",
  "webUrl": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/teams/1drvteam"
}
```

For production scene, please following the [production](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/site_getbypath) version.

Comment: I know it's the beta version, and I'm fine with that. So just to be sure: the beta version does not return the site collection's owner despite the sample response in the document having an "owner" field, and there is currently no way to get the site collection's owner with the Graph (no matter v1.0 or beta) API?